# INSERCION DE VARIABLES EN CAMPO CON INSERT TO

Tags: vba

Buenas tardes estoy tratando de insertar variables en campos de una tabla utilizando insert to pero no me reconoce las variables e tratado de ponerle las comillas pero no doy con la solucion este es el codigo:

```
Private Sub Comando40_Click()
    Dim nom As String
    Dim nro As String
    nom = nombre
    nro = (nro_identificacion)
    intx = DCount("*", "[historial]", " 
    [nro_identificacion]= '" & nro & "'")
    If intx = 0 Then
        Dim SQL As String
        MsgBox (nro)
        MsgBox (nom)
        SQL = "INSERT INTO 
        historial(nombre,nro_identificacion)       
        VALUES ( nom,nro )"
        DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
        DoCmd.OpenForm "historial"
    Else
        DoCmd.OpenForm "historial"
    End If
End Sub
```

Por favor agradeceria altamente ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que en tu codigo  estas insertando el nombre de las variables en vez del valor de las variables

Para concatenar textos en vba se usa el simbolo "&", mira como quedaria tu codigo :

> SQL = "INSERT INTO 
>           historial(nombre,nro_identificacion)
>           VALUES ( '" & nom & "','" & nro & "' )"

Puedes probar si te funciona estas lineas?

nota : El simbolo " ' " solo es necesario cuando insertas valores alfanumericos , si trabajas con numeros puedes obviarlo

Comment: That was the problem, thank you for your cooperation, you have a point in your favor good by

Comment: muchas gracias Arturo!